# Question about Mumford's article

Tags: algebraic-geometry, quadratic-forms

I'm reading the following article by Mumford speaking about theta characteristic.
[Mumford's article](http://www.dam.brown.edu/people/mumford/alg_geom/papers/1971a--ThetaChar-Numdam.pdf)

I'm trying to understand the definition af the quadric form $q$ on page 184. 
Here my questions:
1) In your opinion what does it mean that $a_i \in E(a)_{p_i}$ define, for $i$ from 1 to $N$, the section $\overline{a} \in E(a)/E(-a)$?
2) How is   $Q$ extended to a quadratic map $E(a) \rightarrow \Omega^{1}_{X}(2a)$?
Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Check the link.

Comment: http://www.dam.brown.edu/people/mumford/alg_geom/papers/1971a--ThetaChar-Numdam.pdf